# Rails AJAX return as result whole HTML without body part

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a render

When I paste it in index view page it works. But when I use AJAX:

```
$('.more').on('click', function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "/more",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(result){
        $('.posts').append(result);
    }
})
});
```

Posts_Controller

```
def more
    render partial: "type", locals: { count: 30 }
end
```

Routes:

```
post "/more" => "posts#more"
```

Partial calls "_type.html.erb" in /views/posts/

So, when I click the page loads 20 seconds and returns whole HTML without body part. So I have 2 headers and 2 footers.

How can I fix it and can render it in body part?

Comment: Please be more specific. In which files is are those code-snippets. Describe a little more... Otherwise it's hard to guess where the mistake hides. Remember, we do not see your setup.

Comment: @Tom I update my question. If you want to know something ask me please

Answer (score 0):

Specify a dataType for your requests:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/more",
  type: "POST",
  dataType : 'script',
  success: function(result){
    $('.posts').append(result);
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Error 422: Unprocessable Entity

Comment: rake routes shows that your routes are set up correctly? There are quite a few similar 422-error posts on SO. Hard to detect the problem without the content of your partial.